How can I make my particles follow the emitter when it's having a motion animation?
How do I make sure the particles don’t get left behind when the emitter starts motion animating?
What I want to happen is for the particles to move along with the emitter as it animates without messing the particles positions, but I can’t seem to make it work. Does anyone know how to do this?

